# Automatically format statement when I type a ; (semicolon) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning JAVA and I'm using Eclipse.
In Visual Studio,when I type a ; after a statement like this:

```
b=b+a
```

it's automatically changes to:

```
b = b + a;
```

How do I add this function to Eclipse ?

I searched in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
and didn't find it.
Thanks.

Comment: Just use shift-ctrl-F to format your entire source, why have it assign an action to a character?

Comment: personally I would punch my computer(and eventually kill myslf) if IDE would decide to format my text each time I type `;`. as suggested probably better to get used to ctrl+shift+f to format.

Comment: I get used to it.
Is there a way to change from shift-ctrl-F to type a ; ?

Comment: The duplicate asks about Javascript, but the answers are the same.

Comment: But there isn't an answer to my question?
 Is there a way to change from shift-ctrl-F to type a ;

Answer (score -1):

You can setup automatic code formatting on file save.
Go to Java > Editor > Save Actions and setup it to either format all lines in file or only edited lines.

Comment: Not what he asked for.  The poster clearly wants formatting to happen as he types; e.g. whenever he ends a statement with a semicolon.